# What technical issues should I be aware of when re-mapping a LUN from one host to another?

Tags: storage-area-network, ibm, aix

I inherited an IBM System Storage DS4000 SAN with an AIX environment running Oracle RAC (3 nodes).  One of the nodes crashed, so I got the system up and running with 2 nodes; however, the node that crashed was the node that was managing the backups.  The backups were stored on a LUN in the SAN.

Due to the lack of documentation, I can see how they're mapped from `/etc/filesystems`, but I'm not sure how the AIX environment mapped these LUNs at bootup (other than the mapping association from the SAN management interface).  I want to re-map the LUNs used for backups from the old node to one of the remaining nodes, but I'm concerned about losing the data on the LUNs.

I found some instructions [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixstorage/index.html?ca=dat-), but that seems like it's only for new LUNs.  If I re-map the LUN to a new host, would the existing data on that LUN stay intact?

### **Update 1:**

It looks like I knew less than I thought.

I created a new array on my storage controller called **test** and a new LUN called **logbackup** to test my theory and mapped it to one of the nodes as LUN **12**.

On that node, when I ran `cfgmgr`, I ran into an error and followed [these](http://version7x.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/0514-604-cannot-access-the-cudv-object-class-in-the-device-configuration-database/) instructions to resolve it.

With cfgmgr working, I thought I'd be able to see the LUN, but I don't--or at least, the output of `lspv`, `lscfg` and `lsdev -Cc Disk` don't give me the information I can easily translate.

I've unmapped it and remapped the LUN a few times, but there is no change to the list of hdisks when I run cfgmgr.

### **Update 2:**

Looks like I was reading my `lscfg` output incorrectly.  I changed the LUN from 12 to 255 and saw a change in the `lscfg`.  It mapped the LUN to **hdisk16** so I added it as a physical volume using `chdev -l hdisk16 -a pv=yes`.  Then, running `fget_config -Av`, I was able to confirm the LUN mapped properly.  Now, it's just a matter of mounting it, writing to it, then migrating it to my other node to see if the data stays intact.

Comment: What's your question? Do you need help figuring out how to get it to mount? Or are concerned that mounting the volume will mess something up?

Comment: I am concerned that re-mapping the LUN will require me to wipe the data before I can use it on a "new" system (same OS, different box).  Are my concerns unfounded?  And if I re-map it from the SAN management interface, what service in AIX picks it up? Or do I need to reboot for a process to pick it up?

Comment: can you tell us more about the actual SAN, MUCH more, is this FC/iSCSI/FCoE etc., adapter types - everything please

Comment: FiberChannel SCSI